# In GWT need to set the value of list box to the one,that was was selected in other selection

Tags: gwt, listbox

I have a full search panel with listbox whose value are read from DB.when a item in listbox selected and search is made.If the results are not found the search panel is condensed (one more search panel) and in condensed search ,we can change the search criteria ,selected a different item in the list box .after changing the search criteria and if search is made ,when the full search panel appears,the value of the list box in full search panel should be same as the one changed/selected in the condensed search panel.
How can we accomplish this.

In simple - If i have two list boxes, load a list box and set the value of the listbox same the other listbox.If value of one listbox is changed, the other should be changed and the value of this listbox is set with the value selected in the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following

```
//you have something like this
ListBox listbox1;
ListBox listbox2;

//add a change handler
listbox1.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {

@Override
public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) 
{
      int index = listbox1.getSelectedIndex();
      //do your update code here for listbox2
      //like a listbox2.setSelectedIndex(index) or something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see its an easy implementation. Add a value change handler on the first listbox and do whatever you want in onChange method.

Regarding your panel need to be collapsed when there is no search results, you can always use vertical panel and set its height to 100% and add another panel to it or Use Dock Panel and add panels to south or best use disclosure panel and play around with it.